# Does wget have a download history?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, download, wget

I have used wget to download several compressed packages(in a failed attempt to manually emulate apt-get, if that is of any significance), and I don't remember the packages' locations.
Is it possible to see the wget download history(I want to see it in order to erase all the downloads I've made)? Or maybe is there a more general operating system download history, including what has been downloaded by all network utilities and browsers?

I am running Linux. (Ubuntu 13.04 to be more specific, although this is probably irrelevant)

Comment: wget doesn't have that option, AFAIK, unless you specify a logfile, or if your shell has some sort of memory.

Answer (score 6):

No.

Your best chance is to check your `.bash_history` (or your shells equivalent)

If you know roughly what the files are named you can use `locate` to find them.

Answer (score 3):

Or write a wrapper to log it,

```
$ sudo mv /usr/bin/wget /usr/bin/wget.orig
$ sudo touch /usr/bin/wget
$ sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/wget
$ sudo touch /var/log/wget.log
$ sudo chmod 666 /var/log/wget.log
```

then, edit `/usr/bin/wget` as below

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $@ >> /var/log/wget.log
/usr/bin/wget.orig $@
```

Comment: You can use a simpler and not a system-wide wrapper: `alias wget='wget -a /var/log/wget.log'`.